# jQuery ui Dialog not working when clicked to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to modify a web page template which is based on bootstrap and jquery. I tried to add a dialog like in this [page](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated) but it's not working. (It's the button that's not working on "**Open Positions**" section)

Below you can download my files. You can check index.html file.

I add this javascript from the [link](http://student.cankaya.edu.tr/~c0711058/demo.zip)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

And added following lines for that javascript:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Contact Us">
    <p>info@info.info</p>
</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Why it's not working?

**Another question;** instead of using this jquery ui component, how can i jump to content to "Contact Us" section from "Open Positions" section? This also i wonder because they both in same html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `show`?

```
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "show" );
});
```

Got the error in your file: It is incorrect reference to the CSS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
```

---

There's an extra reference to jQuery twice that caused the issue. Please remove the other version of jQuery and move all the scripts to the bottom.

Comment: @TimurAykutYILDIRIM Try removing the line `autoOpen: false,`?

Comment: It works with your code @TimurAykutYILDIRIM, please check this out: http://jsbin.com/difapezosiho/1/edit

Comment: Did you add the CSS, BTW?

Comment: Yes i did add the css. Would you mind downloading the file in my question? You can see in there is an index.html file. These javascript code are in that file and contary of jsbin, they're not working in there

Comment: In your code, it says `$ is undefined`, that means, you have forgot to include jQuery? Lemme check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59180/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-timur-aykut-yildirim).